# lesscss - Are mixins also "Lazy loaded" like variables?

Tags: less, mixins

I just found out that variables in less are "lazy loaded" (as discribed here: http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading ) in the sense that if you set up a variable, use it and then set it to another value the complied code will use that last set value.

i.e.

```
@w: 30%;

.myclass {
   width: @w;
}
```

would compile to:

```
.myclass {
   width: 50%
}
```

would the same apply to mixins?

i.e. 
will

```
.mycolor() {
   color: red;
}

.myclss {
  .mycolor()
}

.mycolor() {
   color: blue;
}
```

compile to: (no lazy)

```
.myclass {
   color:red;
}
```

or (lazy):

```
.myclass {
   color:blue;
}
```

Comment: They merge, in order (following the cascade rules). Check for yourself: http://lesstester.com/

Comment: Btw, we have some drift in terminology here... Strictly speaking "lazy loading" does not necessarily mean "override" (the "variable overriding concept" is essentially just the "last definition wins" principle). "Lazy loading" usually means simply "can be used before defined" (though Less "lazy loading" goes slightly deeper than that: notice how local `@a` affects global `@var` value in the local scope of the second example in lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading). In other words, to say it precisely: "Lazy Loading" does apply to mixins, but "Last Definition Wins" does not.

Comment: I think it's more accurate to say that the mixins are not "merged" (nor "lazy loaded"), so much as calling a mixin will evaluate and return each mixin that matches. This is similar to the concept in CSS where referencing a class in your HTML would import the properties and values of each class. So, CSS looks up and applies each matching class, and Less does the same here with mixins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, They are not Lazy-loaded

As noted in a comment, mixins "merge" their values if they have the same name. So your code will produce this:

```css
.myclss {
  color: red;
  color: blue;
}
```

Which, in the case of calling the same property twice (as your code does), effectively makes the CSS become equivalent to it having been "Lazy-loaded" because the "final" property value is the one used. So the above will be translated by browsers as:

```css
.myclss {
  color: blue;
}
```

But it is not correct to view it as lazy loading, because if other properties are present, they just merge. So:

```css
.mycolor() {
   color: red;
   opacity: 0.3;
}

.myclss {
  .mycolor()
}

.mycolor() {
   color: blue;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Becomes:

```css
.myclss {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.3;
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

True "Lazy-loading" like the variables would have just overwritten the first set of property calls.