# LessCSS: lazy-loading of unlocked variable reversed

Tags: less

In reference to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426620/lesscss-are-mixins-also-lazy-loaded-like-variables) and [the docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading).

If you simply define a variable twice, the 2nd definition gets lazy loaded as expected but if you do this through a mixin, it seems to be reversed, so the first unlock is applied.

```
.mixin(@input) {
  @width: @input;
}

.selector {
  width: @var;
}

@var: 30px;
@var: 40px;

.mixin(20px);
.mixin(30px);

.selector-2 {
  width: @width;
}
```

Output:

```
.selector {
  width: 40px;
}
.selector-2 {
  width: 20px;
}
```

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable in a mixin is exposed into its calling scope *only* if the scope does not already have such variable defined. (There's no dedicated section in the docs, but it's mentioned [here](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature)).

In your example `.mixin(30px)` has no effect because `@width` is already unlocked into the scope by the previous `.mixin` call (i.e. `.mixin(20px)`).

There's discussion regarding this behaviour [here](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1892), but it seems there's no way to change it without breaking many important Less design patterns.

### -

Btw., another related example:

```
.mixin() {
    @width: 10px;
}

.mixin() {
    @width: 20px;
}

.selector {
   .mixin();
    width: @width;
}
```

In this case the result is `20px` because both mixins are expanded simultaneously and the last `@width` definition wins.